# What does the outer_k option do in the krylov root finding method?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm using scipy to do a root solve. I'm using the `krylov` method because it allows for very large problems to be solved. I've got it working just fine but I'm trying to tune the parameters. My understanding from reading the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton_krylov.html), is that the `outer_k` parameter is some sort of indication of how good an approximation the jacobian will be, however, it doesn't seem to change my iteration values (I'm running verbose/disp = True).

Can someone please provide some more info on the `outer_k` parameter?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [scipy.sparse.linalg.lgmres](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lgmres.html) and check out the papers linked in the references for more information.

Googling gives PDFs for the papers: https://www.google.com/search?q=A%20Technique%20for%20Accelerating%20the%20Convergence%20of%20Restarted%20GMRES

The brief explanation is that the algorithm keeps `k` "representative" vectors of the previous Krylov subspace when doing GMRES restart, when inverting the implicit Jacobian matrix.